# NSArray can't shuffle

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to use the new shuffle method to shuffle my array: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1640855-shuffledarray?language=objc. But I just get an error saying: `No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'shuffledArray'`.

This is my code:

```
NSArray *shuffledArray = [array shuffledArray];
```

And my project is iOS 10.0+

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you can see on the right column of the documentation, although this is a method on `NSArray`, it's located in the `GameplayKit` framework.

You need to import the framework :

```
#import <GameplayKit/GameplayKit.h>
```

Comment: Thank you! The error went away, but the app crashed when I tried to execute the code with this error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSArrayI shuffledArray]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1700ef200'"

Comment: @Peter Answer is to link binary, as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47404093/calling-shuffledarray-method-crashes-app

Answer (score 2):

You should always use `@import` for this, as it offers [some advantages over #import of frameworks](http://www.davitsiradeghyan.com/post/130287171375/import-vs-import-in-objective-c). So on this case it would be:

`@import GameplayKit;`