# Calling "shuffledArray" method Crashes App

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to use the new `shuffledArray` method to shuffle the elements in an `NSMutableArray`. I have the Array declared:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *mArray;
```

Then I call the method

```
mArray = [[self.mArray shuffledArray] mutableCopy];
```

But I'm getting the exception:

```
-[__NSArrayM shuffledArray]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1c4451340
```

I've imported the `GameplayKit` Framework as well, and my app's target is iOS 10.0 so I'm not sure what's wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to link the framework to your project as well, not just import it.

[image: Linked frameworks and libraries xcode]