# Create an array from images in a folder and present a given number of them at random (Objective-C)

Tags: arrays, objective-c, image

I am trying to display a predesignated number of .PNG images (e.g. 20) at random from a folder containing a much larger number of images (120).

Here is my code based on the several examples I could find; I am calling this method within viewDidLoad.

```
-(void)displayImagesInRandomOrder {

    // Obtain set number of attempts
    imageArrayLength = 20; // arbitrary choice in this example
    
    // Build array from all (120) .PNG images in folder
    NSArray *_imageArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@".png" inDirectory:@"(Folder directory)/."];

    // Create a random integer for each of the (120) images in the array
    int randomIndex = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t) _imageArray.count);
    
    // Select an image from the array using the random number
    UIImage *randomImage = [_imageArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
    
    // Add the UIImage to a UIImageView and display it on the screen
    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:randomImage];
    
    // Set position of the image
    tempImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

}
```

All help/advice graciously received, since I have been staring at this for far too long. Many thanks in advance :)

**EDIT ///**

Here is the first of my revised methods to build an array of 20 images selected at random from the folder:

```
NSMutableArray *imageQueue;

- (void)buildArrayOfRandomImages {
    
    // Build array of pathnames to images in folder
    NSArray *pathArray = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"(Folder directory)"];
    
    // Obtain preset number of attempts
    imageQueueLength = 20;
    
    // Create image queue (new array) of predetermined length

    // use a loop to add correct number of images to image queue  
    for(int i = 1; i <= imageQueueLength; i++) {

        // Select an integer at random for each image in the array of pathnames
        int randomIndex = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t) [pathArray count]);

        // Add images to the image queue
        [imageQueue arrayByAddingObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[pathArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex]]];
    }
}
```

Here is the second method:

```
- (void)displayImageFromArray {

    // Add the UIImage to a UIImageView and display it on screen
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[imageQueue objectAtIndex:imageCount]];
    
    // Set screen position of image
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    
    // increment count every time method is called
    imageCount++;
}
```

I felt confident that this would work, but the imageQueue array remains empty from the `buildArrayOfRandomImages` method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if we can help you along:

> ```
> -(void)displayImagesInRandomOrder {
>
>    // Obtain set number of attempts
>    imageArrayLength = 20; // arbitrary choice in this example
>
>    // Build array from all (120) .PNG images in folder
>   NSArray *_imageArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathsForResourcesOfType:@".png" inDirectory:@"(Folder directory)/."];
> ```

This produces an array of *paths* (see the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsbundle/1413058-pathsforresourcesoftype?language=objc)). What is the value of this array when you run your code? Are any paths found?

> ```
>    // Create a random integer for each of the (120) images in the array
>    int randomIndex = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t) _imageArray.count);
>    
>    // Select an image from the array using the random number
>    UIImage *randomImage = [_imageArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex];
> ```

You have an array of *paths*, indexing it won't produce a `UIImage`. Read *Creating Image Objects* in the `UIImage` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage?language=objc).

> ```
>    // Add the UIImage to a UIImageView and display it on the screen
>    UIImageView *tempImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:randomImage];
>    
>    // Set position of the image
>    tempImageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
> }
> ```

There is no code here to select 20 elements. When you want to select *N* different cards at random from a deck of playing cards how do you do it? Now read the `NSArray` [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray?language=objc)... HTH

---

**Addendum After Your Comment & Question Edit**

You've made some good progress, but as you say it still doesn't work. Let's take a look at your new code:

> Here is the first of my revised methods to build an array of 20 images selected at random from the folder:
>
> ```
> NSMutableArray *imageQueue;
> ```

There are a couple of problems here, one design, one programming:

1. **Never** use a global variable just to return a value from a method
2. This declares a variable, `imageQueue`, which is capable of storing a reference to an `NSMutableArray`. All objects need to be created, you don't create an array here, and this variable will have the value `nil` – i.e. it references nothing.

Try a design along the lines of:

```
- (NSArray *) buildArrayOfRandomImagesWithLength:(NSUInteger)imageQueueLength
{
   // create a mutable array to hold the images
   NSMutableArray *imageQueue = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:imageQueueLength];

   // your code to fill the array
   ...

   // return the final array, by convention immutable (NSArray) so copy
   return [imageQueue copy];
}
```

Back to your code:

> ```
> - (void)buildArrayOfRandomImages {
>    
>    // Build array of pathnames to images in folder
>    NSArray *pathArray = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:@"(Folder directory)"];
> ```

There is nothing wrong with this *per se*, but have you checked (using the debugger or logging statements) that `pathArray` contains any elements? While `(Folder Directory)` is a valid name for a folder did you actually call your folder this name?

> ```
>    // Obtain preset number of attempts
>    imageQueueLength = 20;
>    
>    // Create image queue (new array) of predetermined length
>
>    // use a loop to add correct number of images to image queue  
>    for(int i = 1; i <= imageQueueLength; i++) {
>
>        // Select an integer at random for each image in the array of pathnames
>        int randomIndex = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t) [pathArray count]);
> ```

Again there is nothing wrong with this *per se*, it produces a random index for you. However it could produce the same index more than once, do you not want 20 different images?

My playing card analogy obviously was detailed enough: How do you typically select *N* random cards from a deck? You *shuffle* the deck and then *deal* the required *N* cards off the *top*. Take another look at `NSArray`...

> ```
>        // Add images to the image queue
>        [imageQueue arrayByAddingObject:[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[pathArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex]]];
>    }
> }
> ```

This doesn't do what you expect. The method `arrayByAddingObject:` is from `NSArray` and it creates a *new* `NSArray` from an existing one and the new element, the method then *returns* this new array. This code ignores the return value, thus discarding the new array...

However you don't have an `NSArray` but an `NSMutableArray`, so you don't need to create a new array each time you need to add an object to your *mutable* array. Take a look at `NSMutableArray` again...

> Here is the second method:
>
> ```
> - (void)displayImageFromArray {
>
>    // Add the UIImage to a UIImageView and display it on screen
>    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[imageQueue objectAtIndex:imageCount]];
>    
>    // Set screen position of image
>    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
>    
>    // increment count every time method is called
>    imageCount++;
> }
> ```

First this method should have a declaration like:

```
- (void) displayImage:(NSUInteger)imageCount fromArray:(NSArray *)imageQueue
```

i.e. pass in the required data, don't use global variables. Or better yet just:

```
- (void) displayImage:(UIImage)theImage
```

as there is no need to pass the array & index and if defined this way the image doesn't need to come from an array at all.

However the above declarations are probably insufficient – your method as written won't display any images and the additional code to do that may require a further argument as well.

Why won't it display any images? An `UIImageView` will only display its image on screen if it is part of the current *view hierarchy*. Now that is another whole topic in itself, so unless you've omitted code for brevity you've some more reading to do.

---

**Postscript**

Don't try to extend this question further, that is not how SO works. If in researching and designing your new solution you hit an issue ask a new question on that new issue. You can include a reference to this question so people assisting you can trace back the history.

Comment: Thank you for that, @CRD. I will read through the documentation to which you referred and get back with my progress. Best wishes

Comment: OK, so I have read through the documentation and realised one of the logical steps that I had missed. I think I need to create a new array of 20 images based on the (120) pathnames harvested from the folder. I have decided to split the original method into two, the first of which I hope to create the 'image queue' array containing 20 random images (see edit to above question).

Comment: Many thanks again for your help on this! I have some reading to do :)

Comment: Well, using your advice, I managed to get the imageQueue array populating via the loop; many thanks indeed for getting me this far as I was well and truly stuck! However, as you correctly pointed out, my current loop does not guarantee that I am exracting unique elements at random via pathnames. This is something that I am going to have to think through some more.

Answer (score 0):

@CRD, as requested I didn't update the question any more, but wanted to show you my progress. Many thanks again for getting me this far!!

[As you sensibly suggested, I will limit this thread to the creation of the array of randomly selected images, since displaying them is quite a different issue.]

**Solution 1** (seems to work but inelegant):

```
- (NSArray *) buildArrayOfRandomImagesWithLength:(NSUInteger)imageQueueLength {
    
    // Build array of pathnames to images in folder (nil directory was the only one that actually worked for me)
    NSArray *pathArray = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];
    
    // Create a mutable array to hold the images
    NSMutableArray *imageQueue = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:imageQueueLength];
    
    // Fill the imageQueue array using pathnames
    for(int i = 1; i <= imageQueueLength; i++) {
        // Select a random integer
        int randomIndex = arc4random_uniform((uint32_t) [pathArray count]);
        // Use the random integer to select a pathname and create an image object
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[pathArray objectAtIndex:randomIndex]];
        // Ensure all elements are unique
        if (![imageQueue containsObject:image]) {
           // Add image to the image queue
           [imageQueue addObject:image];
        } else {
           i--; // ensure the array is the correct length
        }
    }
    // Return the final array, by convention immutable (NSArray) so copy
    return [imageQueue copy];
}
```

**Solution 2:** (much more elegant but requires an import of the `GameplayKit` Framework, which also must be linked to the project - see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47404462/11137617)

```
- (NSArray *) buildArrayOfRandomImagesWithLength:(NSUInteger)imageQueueLength {
    // Build array of pathnames to images in folder
    NSArray *pathArray = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:nil];
    
    //Create a shuffled copy of pathArray
    NSArray *shuffledPaths;
    shuffledPaths = [pathArray shuffledArray];
    
    // Create a mutable array to hold the images
    NSMutableArray *imageQueue = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:imageQueueLength];

    // Fill the image queue array using pathnames
    for(NSUInteger i = 1; i <= imageQueueLength; i++) {   
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[shuffledPaths objectAtIndex:(i - 1)]];
        [imageQueue addObject:image];
    }
    // Return the final array, by convention immutable (NSArray) so copy
    return [imageQueue copy];
}
```

**Solution 3:** (avoids importing `GameplayKit` by using a separate array shuffling method, based largely on this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56656/11137617, which itself is based on the Fisher–Yates shuffle that @CRD recommended)

```
- (NSArray *) buildArrayOfRandomImagesWithLength:(NSUInteger)imageQueueLength {
    // Build array of pathnames to images in folder
    NSString *directory = nil;
    NSArray *pathArray = [[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]] pathsForResourcesOfType:@"png" inDirectory:directory];
    
    //Create a shuffled copy of pathArray
    NSArray *shuffledPaths;
    shuffledPaths = [self shuffleArray:pathArray];
    
    // qCreate a mutable array to hold the images
    NSMutableArray *imageQueue = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:imageQueueLength];
    // Fill the image queue array using pathnames
    for(NSUInteger i = 1; i <= imageQueueLength; i++) {
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[shuffledPaths objectAtIndex:(i - 1)]];
        [imageQueue addObject:image];
    }
    // Return the final array, by convention immutable (NSArray) so copy
    return [imageQueue copy];
}
```

Array shuffling method:

```
- (NSArray *) shuffleArray:(NSArray*)array {
    NSMutableArray *shuffledArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:array];
    
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [shuffledArray count] - 1; ++i) {
        NSInteger remainingCount = [shuffledArray count] - i;
        NSInteger exchangeIndex = i + arc4random_uniform((u_int32_t )remainingCount);
        [shuffledArray exchangeObjectAtIndex:i withObjectAtIndex:exchangeIndex];
    }
    return [shuffledArray copy];
}
```

Comment: Shuffling, or a variant/optimisation of it, is probably preferable; for the algorithm you have you want to check the path *before* you load the image. The simple answer you seek is in the `NSArray` documentation, but if you want to optimise head over to Wikipedia and look up Fisher-Yates, in both cases don't give up too early in the document...

Comment: Thank you again @CRD. I found the `shuffledArray` method within the `NSArray` documentation (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsarray/1640855-shuffledarray?language=objc). This works fantastically out of the box (see my second silution in my answer) but appears to require `GameplayKit`, which I probably won't be able to rely upon when I have finished (the module I am trying to build will fit into an existing framework that doesn't link to `GameplayKit`). Therefore, I will try to create something bespoke that utilises Fisher-Yates, as you suggested.

Comment: I've now added a third 'version' of a solution to this, using a separate array shuffling method. I guess isolating the remaining issues in this way is the best approach. I will try to optimise the shuffling method as I study the Fisher-Yates variants some more :) Thanks again!